# PhpStorm and workspace issue

Tags: phpstorm

I have the newest version of PhpStorm.

Previously I worked with  Eclipse and had the opportunity to see my whole workspace. In PhpStorm I need to open one instance per project.

In my daily workflow I need to search for strings in my workspace. In 
PhpStorm I would need to switch from instance to instance and need to execute the string search again and again per instance.

Is there another solution or do I really need to execute my search multiple times?

In addition eclipse had the "Open Resource" function for the whole workspace. Does PhpStorm offers the Open Resource for whole workspace too?

Answer (score 0):

> In PhpStorm I need to open one instance per project.

That's correct -- currently having more than one project in one frame is not supported.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

> Is there another solution or do I really need to execute my search multiple times?

You can always attach any folder (from any project) to current project as **Additional Content Root** (will be listed as separate branch in Project View panel).

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Project | Directories --> "Add Content Root" button`.

Note that it will still be treated as one project (no separate settings) -- additional content root is treated as just a bunch of files/folders.

> In addition eclipse had the "Open Resource" function for the whole workspace. Does PhpStorm offers the Open Resource for whole workspace too?

Look for commands under `Navigate` menu.

`Navigate | File...` <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> (using Default keymap) is
most likely what you need.

---

Useful info:

1. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+for+Users+of+Eclipse+PDT+and+Eclipse-based+IDEs
2. PhpStorm has separate keymap that similar to what Eclipse uses.

Comment: Open Resource means, you can search in your current project for a resource like js, css, php, ... files. In eclipse you can search for a resource in whoile workspace